# Sometimes, rigid body works!

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm trying to simulate a very basic rigid body setup. I want it to start from frame 297 (not from the beginning). I do this by animating the **Dynamic** property. Everything works but at the first few frames only. I mean when I enable the Dynamic say at frame 23 it works and the object starts to fall down at frame 23. When I enable the Dynamic say at frame 80 or 200 or 297 or whatever, it doesn't work. It seems that it's something to do with catch or baking or something similar. How can I solve this? It doesn't calculate the physics of the later frames.

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: @Chris Thanks I already knew the answer a few seconds after i posted this question. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I've just discovered it. I can control the cache from the Scene Properties tab. I thought it is in the physics tab just like particle system and some other physics systems.